# Grab only table data from a PDF in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've been trying to extract table data in a pdf to load in to a jtable. i am using itext API for this. this is what i did so far

```
    //imports
      import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
      import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

    //code:

       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("quatation.pdf");

                // pageNumber = 3
                String textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 3);
                String[] lines = textFromPage.split("\r\n|\r|\n");



                for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(" no: " + i + " " + lines[i]);
                }


                reader.close();
```

in this way i get all rows in the pdf file. i just need the table content in the pdf file. any suggestions?

Comment: You surely have read the numerous stack overflow q&a on extraction of table data from PDF. Thus, you do know that in general there is no difference between table content and non-table content in PDFs, in particular there is no internal "table starts here" or "table ends here" tag. You must be aware, therefore, that there is nothing sensible to tell you in general but that there may be a chance if you can find indicators for table start or end which reliably are used in the PDFs you want to extract from, e.g. some heading "Table x: xxxx" in some special font reliably in front of each table.

Comment: yeah i guess its a good idea. thanx for the clarification.